# Retrieving YouTube title, comments with users tokens increasing quota usage

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

In YouTube v3 API does using users tokens to retrieve video information like videos title, thumbnail, comments increase the daily usage quota of user which is 10000 per day. I am using test user's to get the tokens and making call to YouTube api which giving me the info but increasing my quota usage.

Answer (score 0):

The more you use the api the more of your quota will be used. [determine_quota_cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)  remember youtube quota is cost based not request based.

The cost of the request you are making is going to denote how much of your quota is removed.

If you need more then the 10k development quota you can request just fill out and submit the [YouTube API Services - Audit and Quota Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form).

[Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc)

Comment: "The more you use the api" but I use only the token of users to call and retrieve video details, not API so how can it increase quota usage?

Comment: No your application has a number of tokens not the user.